# Finding the odd row between two tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with the following schema

```
id, fruit
```

In TableA the values are like this:

```
A01, Apple
A02, Orange
A03, Pineapple
A03, Pineapple
A05, Banana
```

In TableB the values are like this:

```
A01, Apple
A02, Orange
A03, Pineapple
A04, Pineapple
A05, Banana
```

How can I reconcile these two tables to return just the duplicate row A03 in TableA? Like a one-to-one comparison of the tuples and returning the odd tuple.

I tried the minus query like below

```
Select * from TableA
minus
Select * from TableB
```

But that's not returning the result set I expected.

Comment: Is Table B really needed?

Comment: your q is not really clear

Comment: according to your q leaving A04 pineapple wll shold be returned if you comsiders table b also

Comment: your query will retrurn a null set

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to exclude the rows from A that are present in B **and only the exact number of them**. I guess you could simply assign a row number to them:

```
SELECT "id", "fruit", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "id", "fruit" ORDER BY NULL) AS rn
FROM TableA
MINUS
SELECT "id", "fruit", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "id", "fruit" ORDER BY NULL) AS rn
FROM TableB
```

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3414afc8fc0a08eec3f5737230a4fa41)

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, on AskTom, Marco Stefanetti came up with the following brilliant approach. It only requires each table to be read once, and it does only one sort.

The context is the most general possible: the query will find rows that exist in one table but not in the other, but - when duplicates are allowed - it will ALSO find rows that exist in both tables, but they have different number of duplicates.

I create the test data in the WITH clause; when you test the solution, you can remove it and start with the last SELECT statement.

```
with
  tablea (id, fruit) as (
    select 'A01', 'Apple'     from dual union all
    select 'A02', 'Orange'    from dual union all
    select 'A03', 'Pineapple' from dual union all
    select 'A03', 'Pineapple' from dual union all
    select 'A05', 'Banana'    from dual
  )
, tableb (id, fruit) as (
    select 'A01', 'Apple'     from dual union all
    select 'A02', 'Orange'    from dual union all
    select 'A03', 'Pineapple' from dual union all
    select 'A04', 'Pineapple' from dual union all
    select 'A05', 'Banana'    from dual
  )
select   id, fruit, count(case source when 'tablea' then 1 end) as count_in_a,
                    count(case source when 'tableb' then 1 end) as count_in_b
from     (
           select id, fruit, 'tablea' as source from tablea
           union all
           select id, fruit, 'tableb' as source from tableb
         )
group by id, fruit
having   count(case source when 'tablea' then 1 end) !=
         count(case source when 'tableb' then 1 end)
;

ID  FRUIT     COUNT_IN_A COUNT_IN_B
--- --------- ---------- ----------
A03 Pineapple          2          1
A04 Pineapple          0          1
```

Comment: What happen to `A05`, `A01` and `A02`? I don't think this what the OP want (_How can I reconcile these two tables to return just the duplicate row A03 in TableA?_)

Comment: @sami - they are not returned, because those rows are found identically (and with the same multiplicities) in both tables. The OP is looking to find the DIFFERENCES between the two tables. And, he is only asking for the duplicate from the first table (and not the A04 row from the second) because he is only looking at half the problem. The beauty of Stefanetti's solution is that you can get BOTH in a single pass!

Comment: He did not say _How to find difference between those two tables_ he just say _How can I reconcile these two tables to return just the duplicate row A03 in TableA?_

Comment: @Sami - Try to find the words *the odd tuple* in the original post. That means the tuple that is "out of place", "not matched". And his attempt with MINUS suggests the same thing, except that MINUS de-duplicates first; he needs something like a MINUS ALL, similar to UNION ALL, except that Oracle does not support MINUS ALL (which would consider multiplicities, like UNION ALL does).

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want:

```
Select id, fruit
from TableA
group by id, fruit
having count(*) > 1
minus
Select id, fruit
from TableB;
```

It is not clear that `tableB` is really needed.  If you have other columns that you want, you can express this using `exists`:

```
Select id, fruit
from (select a.*, count(*) over (partition by id, fruit) as cnt
      from TableA a
     ) a
where cnt > 1 and
      exists (select 1 from tableB b where b.id = a.id and b.fruit = a.fruit);
```

Or using `in`:

```
Select id, fruit
from (select a.*, count(*) over (partition by id, fruit) as cnt
      from TableA a
     ) a
where cnt > 1 and
      (a.id, a.fruit) in (select b.id, b.fruit) from tableB);
```

Comment: This will not return anything, because the duplicate row from A is also found in B, so MINUS will not return it.

Comment: (By "this" I meant the first query. The OP stated clearly that he wants to find differences between the tables, so table B is certainly needed. If he just wanted to find duplicates, I suppose he would have asked that.)